# Android Compatibility Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, compatibility

I am working on an android application that uses Google Maps (Google API). At this moment it's just a simple map with a compass, and it gets the address of a location the user clicks. The problem is as follows:

The min SDK version : API level **8**

Target SDK: API level **14**

As I think, this should work properly on the range from **8** to **14** inclusive. But it only works properly on API level **14**. I tested the app on **Android 2.3.3 (API 10)** the compass is missing, and the address functionality is not working either.

To be clear, the question is:

How can compatibility be done right?

Thanks in advance

**Note:** I am using an emulator (on Eclipse) and not a real device.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Have you included the Android Support Library?

Comment: @TJThind I add this now, but nothing changed. I followed this guide http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

Comment: Are there any specific errors in Logcat? Can you post relevant code excerpts? If you have the support library installed you should target the latest release which is not 14. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: Whilst these minimum / target APIs will allow the application to compile correctly, they don't guaruntee that the code won't encounter runtime errors as it tries to access classes / methods that aren't available on an API8 device. Look at your implementation of the Compass / Address functionality, and check you aren't using any functionality that was introduced in later APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Emulators have a lot of trouble with the Google Maps API. To do any real testing with Goole Maps API you should have a real device.

Comment: I second this, don't rely on the emulator.

Comment: Haha, this would be a great excuse to buy a new phone XD